# C Programming: Using function to return size of array

Tags: c, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have been trying to create a function in C that reads in doubles that are then stored into an array. I want to be able to return the size of the array so that I can use it in main. So the purpose of this function is to ask the user to input values into an array and type in ^d (ctrl+d) or EOF to end the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Prototype Declaration
int getdata(double[], int); 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
 double array[20]; 
 int count = 0, max = 20;

 //Calls the getdata function
 count = getdata(array, max); 
 printf("%s%lf%s","Array1: " ,array[1], "\n");  
 printf("%s%d%s", "Count is: ", count, "\n");
 return 0;
}
```

----- (I'm linking modules so these are in different files) -------

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Define getdata.c
int getdata(double values[], int limit){
 printf("%s","Please enter your values into the array.\n");
 int count = 0;
 double n;
 while ((count < limit) && (scanf("%lf",&n) != EOF)) {
  values[count] = n; 
  count++;
 } 
 return count; 
}
```

What happens, though, is that if I break the loop early, the array values pass by fine but the count would just print out 20. I am assuming that the program automatically fills in the rest of the empty indexes with something and continues to increment the count value after I type in EOF. What can I do so that the program can correctly get the amount of values inputted? I do not code much in C. I mostly do my work in C++. I am familiar with passing by reference but using C.

Comment: Check the documentation of `scanf` to see what it returns

Comment: Note that the declaration of `getdata()` should be in a header that is included in both the file defining `main()` and in the file defining `getdata()`.  That way, the header file serves as the glue that checks that both source files agree on the correct declaration/definition of `getdata()`.

Comment: This code seems to be working fine: `echo 3 4 5 | main` prints `Count is: 3`.

Comment: Aside: `scanf("%lf",&n) != EOF` does not cover the case where `scanf` returns `0`. Better is `scanf("%lf",&n) == 1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware that `scanf()` won't swallow input that can't be converted. If there is a problem then it leaves the (faulty) input in the stream for you to fail to convert on the next iteration of the loop. So it's repeatedly trying to match the same invalid thing as a double.

I suggest using `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` as a better solution than using `scanf()`, or (at minimum) check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure you got the expected number of fields read (which is `1` in this case). I bet it is returning 0 rather than EOF, so your loop continues until `count` matches `limit`.